# Mount Raid 5 to Ganeti VM

Tags: raid, nfs, zfs, ganeti

I am running a one node Ganeti Server Supermicro MBD-X10SDV-6C+-TLN4F-O with Intel Xeon D-1528 and 32 GB Ram I have the following setup:

- OS Ubuntu 16.04.2
- 2X 250GB SSD's in Raid 1 -> ext4 partition for OS and LVM for Instances
- 3X 1TB WD Red in Raid 5 mounted at /data -> ext4
- 1X 2TB WD Red mounted at /Backup -> ext4

Now for my NextCloud I would like to keep data separated from the Instance disk and just mount the Raid 5 device to the NextCloud instance for data storage, so that I can at any time replace the Ganeti Instance without loosing the data. Other Instances (OpenVpn, dnsmaq, Radius, etc..) don't need access to the Raid device, hence I will be using configuration management.

What is the best way to achieve this, is it better just to mount it as NFS or maybe convert the ext4 to ZFS and NFS mount? Is there any other way?

Thanks in advanced